# Simulate a series of button clicking in code and wait for effects to finish

Tags: c#, wpf

I have series of buttons with EFFECTS that I'd like simulate clicking in code.  The problem is that when I run "someFunction" the effects all trigger at about the same time.  I'd like a button to click, then wait for the effect to finish then proceed on to the other buttons.  I've tried using Thread.sleep but that doesn't work. Can anyone give me some pointers on how this can be accomplished?  Also, is it possible to simulate clicking on multiple buttons at the same time?

Thanks for any help!

```
someFunction() {
    button1.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent));
    //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100); doesn't work wait for effect to finish

    button2.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent));
    //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);  doesn't work

    button3.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent));
    //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);  doesn't work

    button4.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent));
}

<Button Name="buttonRed" Background="Red" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1"
        Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Click="buttonRedClick">
    <Button.BitmapEffect>
        <BlurBitmapEffect x:Name="redBlur"  Radius="0" />
    </Button.BitmapEffect>
    <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetName="redBlur"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Radius"
                        From="0" To="40" Duration="0:0:0.3"
                        AutoReverse="True" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
</Button>
```

Comment: What kind of 'Effects' are you referring to? Do you mean Storyboard actions or is this some type of c# code that is run when the button is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at this [article](http://galasoft.ch/mydotnet/articles/article-2006102701.aspx) by Laurent Bugnion.

From above article:

> Note that it is also possible to use the [BeginTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.begintime.aspx) property of the
>   animation object to delay an animation, for example in order to
>   cascade animations. Another way is to use the [Completed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.completed.aspx) event, which
>   can be set in the XAML code, or in the code-behind. This event implies
>   that the corresponding method must be present in the code-behind, thus
>   it is not applicable for pure XAML applications.

Answer (score 0):

Thread.sleep will not work as it defines the sys.val realization, so you can use the following code:

there's the error :    `<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">`

instead it should be: `<Event.Trigger.Sleep RoutedEvent="Button.Click">`